# Saving iterator from python's zip

Tags: python, generator

So, I have a function that I have to call a ton of times. That function iterates through a list by pairs like so:

```
for a, b in zip(the_list, the_list[1:]):
    # do stuff with a and b
```

I'd really like to precompute the result of `zip(the_list, the_list[1:])`, so that I can reuse it and not have to calculate it each time I call this function.

Unfortunately, since `zip(...)` is a generator, I can't reuse its result. Is there any way that I can reset the generator back to the beginning, or store the zipped tuple list so that I can iterate directly through that?

Comment: Creating a generator doesn't cost you anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buffer a generator to a list like so:

```
z = list(zip(x, y))
```

However, I doubt there'll be much performance benefit in this, since `zip` is itself just iterating over its arguments, which is what you'd end up doing if you buffered it to a list.  There's not really much "computation" going on when you call `zip`.

**Edit:** This assumes you're using Python 3, wherein `zip` really does return a generator.  In Python 2, `zip` returns a list, so you're probably better off reusing this list between function calls.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! Wishful performance-thinking on my part.

Answer (score 0):

```
pairs = list(zip(the_list, the_list[1:]))

for a,b in pairs:
    # etc...
```